# Solana web3.js Transaction ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer

Tags: transactions, buffer, solana

I have experienced a bug in Typescript with Solana package @solana/web3.js. I have developed a wallet application to the point where I generate new keypair, establish connection, receive an airdrop, get list of transacations for my publicKey. However, i am stuck at sending a transaction to other wallets.

I run the code below and the catch method logs the error:
**[ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer]**
My code:

```
import {
  clusterApiUrl,
  Connection,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  Keypair,
  ParsedTransactionWithMeta,
  Transaction,
  SystemProgram,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  PublicKey,
  Signer,
} from '@solana/web3.js';

  const [keypair, setKeypair] = useState<Keypair>();
  const [keypair2, setKeypair2] = useState<Keypair>();
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');

  const generateNewKeys = () => {
    console.log('trying to get new keypair');
    setKeypair(() => Keypair.generate());
    setKeypair2(() => Keypair.generate());
    console.log('Generated new keypair');
  };

  const sendTransaction = async () => {
    console.log('initializing sending');
    if (keypair && keypair2) {
      try {
        console.log('Attempting to send');
        let transaction = new Transaction().add(
          SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
            toPubkey: keypair2.publicKey,
            lamports: amount * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
          }),
        );
        console.log('Created transaction');
        const signer: Signer = keypair;
        await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [signer]);
        updateBalance();
        updateTransactions();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  };
```

When running the sendTransaction function it logs "Attempting to send" but not the "Created transaction" which points to the problem with creating the variable "transaction".

Honestly i'm stuck, I have compared my code to others, and despite no differences it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's a project made using Create React App (CRA) and Webpack 5. Webpack 5 does not automatically perform Node.js API polyfills as it used to, so you need to manually do it.

In practice it means:

```
yarn add -D buffer
```

Also need to override your Webpack config

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(webpackConfig) {
  // ..
  webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = {
    buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
  };

  webpackConfig.plugins = [
    ...webpackConfig.plugins,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
  ];
  return webpackConfig;
};
```

Here is an example of Solana dApp made with CRA and Webpack 5 https://github.com/Bonfida/serverless-merch/blob/master/ui/config-overrides.js